# How do i Fetch this data inside json array

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

I want to fetch data from this http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/velosofy?v=2&alt=json
I can get all the other data but i can't get the "countHint" inside the json array.

This is what i use to get for example the "display":

```
$realUserName = 'velosofy';
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '
v=2&alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

`echo 'displayname = '. $data['entry']['yt$username']['display'].'<br />';`

My questions is: How can i echo the countHint of for example Subscriptions?

Comment: `print_r($data)` So we can see the structure of the array...

Comment: here is the print_r($data) http://pastebin.com/reTse5Zc

Comment: you are getting $ sign inside the string. this may cause the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting count for your code:

```
echo $data["entry"]['gd$feedLink'][0]["countHint"];
```

If you use double quotation for `gd$feedLink`, it won't work as index string contain `$feedlink`. `$feedlink` will be consider as php variable.  So Try with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the json structure changed: echo $data["entry"]['gd$comments']['gd$feedLink']["countHint"];